# In bash script, what is the use of =~ with " " in the right side?

Tags: bash

This is part of a bash script with line numbers shown. I can understand how getopts works in bash, but can't understand line 116. `if [[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~ " $OPTARG " ]]; then` part. Earlier in the script there was

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FS_OPTIONS=("ubuntu" "busybox")
while getopts "hsf:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            if [[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~ " $OPTARG "  ]]; then
                echo "Unsupported filesystem $OPTARG"
                echo "Use ubuntu/busybox"
                exit -1
            else
                echo "ok!"
                export FILESYSTEM=$OPTARG
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done

ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f ubuntu
ok!
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f busybox
ok!
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f ubunt.
Unsupported filesystem ubunt.
Use ubuntu/busybox
```

I changed the condition line to `if [[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~  $OPTARG   ]]; then` and can see the right side is regarded as regular expression. Now I can see

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f ubunt.
ok!
```

This is because the " " was removed and the argument was taken as regexp.

The bash manual says

> An  additional  binary  operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used,
> the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly
> (as in regex(3)).  The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.

This got long before my question.  My first question is : From what I observed above, when the pattern matches, the =~ returns 1. (it has ! before) as opposed to the manual. Am I missing something?
My second questions : What are some use cases of using the original `if [[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~ " $OPTARG " ]]; then`? exploiting regular expression? Because it has " ", it will take the argument as string(without taking it as regular expression). Is there any usefulness for =~ with " "?

Comment: `(it has ! before) as opposed to the manual.` How that's "opposed"? There's `! expression True if expression is false`.

Comment: That said, note that "why" questions on language design are usually off-topic here; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918

Comment: @KamilCuk For example, when I gave `-f ubuntu`, is shows it matched (it printed `ok` above). This means the first `if ( ! ... =~ ... )` part was not taken, meaning the =~ part returned 1. So I gave a match pattern, but the =~ returned 1. (the manual says it returns 0 when it matches). Am I missing something?

Comment: (BTW, `exit -1` isn't generally meaningful in shell: UNIX exit status is an _unsigned_ integer; thus, negative numbers always get converted to positive ones).

Comment: ...as another aside, `[[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~ " $OPTARG " ]]` is not great form. It should be using `[*]` instead of `[@]` in a context where the string isn't allowed to expand into multiple words.

Comment: As another aside -- all-caps variables are used for names either defined by the POSIX specification or which otherwise modify behavior of the shell and other POSIX-defined tools; whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use, and are thus what you should use for new variables you define yourself. See the relevant specification at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace (as setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What's the meaning of the *specific line you asked about*?

Breaking down what's done by `[[ ! " ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} " =~ " $OPTARG " ]]`:

- `" ${FS_OPTIONS[@]} "` is, in this context, a less-clear equivalent to `" ${FS_OPTIONS[*]} "` (since the usual distinction between them would have `[@]` expanding to multiple words, which isn't legal in this context). Thus, in acting like `${FS_OPTIONS[*]}`, we're expanding to the complete list of words in `FS_OPTIONS`, with a separator (first character in IFS, by default a single space) added between them. Also, note that we're adding whitespace at the beginning and end (so our `OPTARG` can be matched in those positions and not just in the middle).
- `" $OPTARG "` pads the string we're looking for with whitespace on both sides, so we can't match a substring.
- With the right-hand side quoted, we're doing a substring search, so we're checking if the contents of `$OPTARG` -- with added whitespace at the beginning and end -- exist anywhere in the full expanded list generated by `${FS_OPTIONS[*]}`.
- The `!` inverts the logical exit status of the rest of the expression (changing a 0 to a 1 or a 1 to a 0).

#### What's the use of that syntax in general?

- A quoted string on the RHS acts as a regular, *unanchored* substring search. That is, `[[ $foo = "bar" ]]` is true only if the variable `foo` expands to exactly `bar`, but `[[ $foo =~ "bar" ]]` is true if the variable `foo` expands to *contain* `bar` anywhere in its contents. This is a useful semantic on its own.
- Quoting is determined character-by-character, not for the full string. As an example of how this can be used:

  ```
  regex_pre='([[:space:]]|^)'
  literal_string='** match this exactly **'
  regex_post='([[:space:]]|$)'

  [[ $foo =~ ${regex_pre}"${literal_string}"${regex_post} ]]
  #          |            |                 |
  #          |            |                 \-> unquoted: acts like a regex
  #          |            \-> quoted: acts like a literal string
  #          \-> unquoted: acts like a regex
  ```

  ...matches `** match this exactly **` only when it's at the start of a string or immediately preceded by whitespace, and also either at the end or immediately succeeded by whitespace, without needing to write a regex for the literal string in between, and without needing to do the pad-with-whitespace trick shown in the question.

Comment: wow, thank you very much for the kind explanation. the last part(regex_pre~ regex_post)  I can't rightnow, but I'll check it later.(just because it's so late here).

Answer (score 0):

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f ubuntu
ok!
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/testbash$ test3.sh -f ubunt.
Unsupported filesystem ubunt.
Use ubuntu/busybox
```

The bash manual says (in the discussion about [`[[...]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b)):

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string

So, to treat the input as a regular expression, plus add literal spaces at the ends, quote the spaces but leave the variable unquoted:

```sh
[[ " ${FS_OPTIONS[*]} " =~ " "$OPTARG" "  ]]
# .........................^^^-------^^^
```

Demonstrating:

```sh
$ OPTARG=ubuntu
$ [[ " ${FS_OPTIONS[*]} " =~ " "$OPTARG" "  ]] && echo Y || echo N
Y

$ OPTARG=ubunt.
$ [[ " ${FS_OPTIONS[*]} " =~ " "$OPTARG" "  ]] && echo Y || echo N
Y

$ OPTARG=ubunt
$ [[ " ${FS_OPTIONS[*]} " =~ " "$OPTARG" "  ]] && echo Y || echo N
N
```